# What is the difference between 'tell' and 'say'

Tags: meaning, verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Nothing to tell” versus “nothing to say”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22984/nothing-to-tell-versus-nothing-to-say)

Both words seem to be used interchangeably. I generally don't differentiate between them and intuitively pick one over the other. Is there a standardized way to distinguish between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb *tell* is transitive, and takes a direct object. The verb *said* does not. You should use *tell* when you're emphasizing the fact that you're communicating something to somebody:

> Let me tell you how to get to San Jose.
>   *Let me say to you how to get to San Jose.
>   Let me tell you a story.
>   *Let me say a story to you.

You should use *say* when there is no communication involved:

> Say "rubber baby buggy bumpers" ten times fast.
>   *Tell me "rubber baby buggy bumpers" ten times fast.

Most of the time, both verbs can be used:

> Tell me you didn't mean that.
>   Say you didn't mean that.

Answer (score 3):

"To say" is simply to speak; to have words coming out of your mouth at some audible level. "To tell" is to communicate a thought to some listener.

There is thus a slight grammatical difference; "to tell" requires that the object be the listener or recipient, and what is/was communicated becomes the object complement. With "to say", what is said is the object, unless a preposition is used to insert a listener as an object.

So, the following are all valid:

> I said, "go away". - *(no listener specified; it must be implied from context)*
>
> I said to Tom, "go away". - *(listener specified as a proper noun)*
>
> I said that Tom should go away. - *(Listener not specified, despite the presence of an object noun; it is part of another statement joined to "I said" with a conjunction)*
>
> I told Tom "go away". - *(listener specified, implication is that Tom received and understood the message)*
>
> I told Tom to go away - *(listener specified, what is told doesn't have to be a quote)*

However, neither of the following are valid:

> I said Tom "go away" - *(requires a preposition to insert an object noun)*
>
> I told "go away" - *(requires an object noun and object complement structure)*

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's more of a preference. You normally "tell" someone something. If I have nothing to tell, it suggests that there's no information, story, or answer to "tell" you. When I have nothing to say, it suggests that I'm either reluctant to say anything, or have nothing to say.

That's how I distinguish between the two, but in terms of their definition given the context, they are largely the same; like you, I don't differentiate between them either.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Say is more general, and can refer to any indicative speech. Tell is a stronger word. It usually signifies either information being conveyed or a command. For example:

> He told me what had happened.
>
> He told me to go away.