# What is correct: "I am saying..." or "I am telling..."?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verbs, progressive-aspect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Nothing to tell” versus “nothing to say”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22984/nothing-to-tell-versus-nothing-to-say)
>   [“Told” vs. “Said to” somebody?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48734/told-vs-said-to-somebody)

Are both of these sentences correct? If so, what is the difference between them? My friend told me that first one is not commonly used. I would be glad if someone can clarify this.

> I am saying this for the second time that I am not coming.

or

> I am telling you this for the second time that I am not coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A native speaker would say neither of those, but something like *This is the second time I've had to tell you that I'm not coming.* In any case, *tell* not *say*, and you don't need both  *this* (after *telling*) and *that I am not coming.*